# Abel transform in pyabel

Tags: python, image

I am using pyabel to perform an abel transform on some data. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import abel

data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

IM = plt.hist2d(x,y,bins=100)[0]
plt.clf()

AIM = abel.Transform(IM, method="hansenlaw", direction="inverse").transform

plt.imshow(AIM)
plt.show()
```

However the result I am getting is not like the one expected (e.g. [here](https://pyabel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_O2_PES_PAD.html)). I am attaching below 2 figures, with the first one being the original image and the second one its inverse abel transform. Why am I seeing that weird trace in the middle? Also why does it looks so blurry still? I would have expected a nice ring on the edge and pretty much empty in the middle.

[image]
[image]